# How do I create a master detail or lookup relationship to ContentVersion?

Tags: custom-object, lookup, master-detail, content, contentversion

I've created my custom object, I want to add a lookup or (ideally) a master detail relationship to ContentVersion. However when I go to create a New Relationship on the custom object, I don't see ContentVersion in the "Related To" drop down list. Is this a permissions issue, or is this just not possible? Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`ContentVersion` can not be the parent of any custom object.

`ContentVersion` can be the child, via a lookup relationship to Custom or Standard objects. This is done by `Setup | Customize | Salesforce CRM Content | Fields | New`

Historically, `ContentVersion` and its related objects `ContentWorkspace, ContentDocument etc.` were acquired through an acquisition and behave without complete adherence to normal standard and custom objects.  There is an Idea I did years ago https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrYFAA0 related to some limitations.